# How do we find the homorphism from $\mathbb{Z_2} \to{\rm Aut}(\mathbb{Z_3} \times \mathbb{Z_3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, automorphism-group, semidirect-product

How do we find the homorphism from $\mathbb{Z_2} \to {\rm Aut}(\mathbb{Z_3} \times \mathbb{Z_3})?$

I know that ${\rm Aut}(\mathbb{Z_3} \times \mathbb{Z_3})$ is isomorphic to $GL_2(\mathbb{Z_3})$.

We know that $\theta :\mathbb{Z_2} \to GL_2(\mathbb{Z_3}) $

Then $\theta(1)$ is mapped to an element of order 2 which should be present in the Sylow - $2$ subgroup of $GL_2(Z_3)$.

Then what automorphism map corresponds to the Sylow $2$ subgroup? What is the structure of the Sylow $2$ subgroup?

Comment: Which homomorphism is $\theta$? Any element of order 2 in a group $G$ gives a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_2 \to G$.

Comment: I am trying to classify group of order 18

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of which homomorphism is $\theta$. Also, what do groups of order $18$ have to do with this problem? As Shaun noted, $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_3)$ has $48$ elements, and that's not divisible by $18$.

Comment: It is completely unclear what you are asking. The question in the first sentence makes no sense since there are lots of homomorphisms, and "Then what automorphism map corresponds to the sylow 2 subgroup?" makes no sense. You need to edit your post to clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Cauchy's Theorem, since $2\mid |GL_2(\Bbb Z_3)|=48$, there exists at least one element $g\in GL_2(\Bbb Z_3)$ of order two. Now

$$\begin{align}
\varphi:\Bbb Z_2&\to GL_2(\Bbb Z_3),\\
z&\mapsto g,\\
e&\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}$$

is a homomorphism, where $z$ is the nontrivial element of $\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: the element $g$ represents some isomorphism of Aut(Z_3*Z_3).I am trying to understand which isomorphism it is?

Comment: Consider the isomorphism that swaps the coordinates, @Antimony.

Comment: How do I prove that $Aut(Z_3 \times Z_3)$ is isomorphic to $GL_2(Z_3)$? Is there any easy proof of it.

Comment: That's a separate question entirely, @Antimony; I suggest you search for it here and, if you can't find nor prove it, ask it as a new post.